# How to access private playlist using spotipy?

Tags: python, spotipy

I'm aware you can access all your public playlists using

```
user_playlist(username)
```

but is there any way to access information from my private playlists?

Comment: Spotipy's own [documentation](http://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#authorized-requests) may help with this...

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the scope parameter in the call to util.prompt_for_user_token() to 'playlist-read-private'.